# Expose all app roles to user or groups in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I currently have a registered app in Azure. This app has app-defined roles. The first role I created shows in the pane but is disabled (grayed out), however, it will be assigned to a user/group upon assigning that role. I created another role today, but that role isn't showing in the pane. So the default behavior when assigning a user/group a role to the application will be to assign the first role. Does anyone know what could be limiting the roles I have defined for the application?

EDIT:

In `App Role` under `Manage` in the `Application Registration`. There are two roles: `role.one` and `role.two` both with `user/group` member access. `enable app role` is checked.

```
Enterprise Application > All Application > MyApp > Users and Groups > Add Assignment
```

On this screen `Select a role` list only `role.one`.

Comment: Perhaps you are able to share images that elaborate? My first thought is your app role could be scoped to only allow Applications as members, instead of allowing Users/Groups

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @scottwtang i updated to provide a response to your question.

Comment: Hey @kevwig85, even i was not able to see the new app role to assign as it is not appeared, but once i refreshed the portal after saving roles , it got reflected and could add that role.

Comment: @kevwig85 If you assign a user with the default role and save, then on `Users and groups` > Select user > `Edit` > `Select a role`; does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was my `app role` description name was `Default Access`, which may have conflicted with an azure pre-defined role or description. I am still not sure, but once I changed the description to "Default Role" it became available.

Answer (score 0):

Iniitially as soon as i created new app role i waas not able to see the new app role to assign as it is not appeared, but once i refreshed the portal after saving roles , it got reflected and could add that role.

So please  try refreshing the portal or try to check the same after few minutes of app role creation.

I tested, and it is working fine for me. AFAIK It maynot be issue from Microsoft end .

First added 3 roles and assigned.

[image]

Then after sometime created 4th role and was able to assign to user or group one or more than one role
[image]

**Note** : Sometimes the reason can be browser cache may . Try to clear the Browers cache and  logout and login again in a portal or try in incognito mode and see . If it is still the same issue please reach out to [support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) they can better help here.